two isp one computer routed access do i need snat?
i have a computer with two nics with two isp.
ISP 1 - is my default gateway, used for all public connections (ETH0, 192.168.0.0/24)
ISP 2 - is used only for one address lets say 8.8.8.8 (ETH1, 10.0.0.0/24)
No i created a routing table which seem to work.
My question is, when do i need snat? or since when do i need snat...
I think i don't need snat, since i could ping 9.9.9.9 over eth0 and 8.8.8.8 over eth1 without dataloss (tcp, stateful)...but my network guy means this can lead to problem without snat....
So, who is right,..
Thx guys.

Check (using tcpdump, Wireshark or similar tool) that you are actually getting the responses from 8.8.8.8 via ETH1/ISP2 and not ETH0/ISP1.
If you do, then everything seems to be OK and I don't see the reason why you might need SNAT. As long as the host in question (ie. 8.8.8.8) "knows" that it should send packets to you via ISP2 and not ISP1, everything is fine. Of course if you don't have control over that host's routing setup, there is probability that this may change in the future, and then probably you might need SNAT or some other changes on your side. But as long as nothing changes on the other side, you are fine.
Probably "your networking guy" thinks a little bit too general, ie. about a situation where you want to use bot ISP1 and ISP2 to general connections to anywhere on the Internet. This may actually lead to some problems (or not, depends on the routing setup on the other side).
But as long as it is only a handful of hosts (in your case, just one) and they all work OK, you don't need to bother.

Yes i already checked with tcpdump. Everythink as expected.
